# ARC semantic issue - No visible @interface

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 UIViewController classes - DocumentViewController and LibraryViewController.

In the class DocumentViewController, I have the following code:

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)linkToPdf withFileName:(NSString *)fileName{
     //some code goes here ... 
}
```

and I am trying to load the DocumentViewController class from LibraryViewController using the code:

```
DocumentViewController *documentViewController = [[DocumentViewController alloc] initWithURL:@"http://investor.google.com/pdf/2012Q4_google_earnings_slides.pdf" withFileName:@"Google Earnings Slides"];
[self presentViewController:documentViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

When I build, I get an error in the LibraryViewController class saying 
No visible @interface for 'DocumentViewController' declares the selector with initWithURL:withFileName:

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Did you add the method declaration in the .h? Did you import the .h file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the method declaration is in `DocumentViewController`'s header file. It should be like this

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)linkToPdf withFileName:(NSString *)fileName;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But there is another method 
`- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` Why is that not declared in the header file ?

Comment: That's automatically a method for `UIViewController` and any of it's subclasses